# Trouble solving a separable ODE with constant

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have $\frac{dx}{dt} = r(x^n)$ where r is a constant.

I've tried to solve as a separable ode and have ended up with

$x^{1-n} = (1-n)(rt+c)$

From here, take logs, solve for $x$ and get

$x=e + e^{(rt+c)/(1-n)} $  which I'm pretty convinced isn't right.

However plugging the ODE into wolfram alpha gives the answer

$x(t) = ((n-1) (c_1-r t))^{1/(1-n)}$ which I equally don't understand.

Comment: Try taking the power $\frac{1}{1-n}$ instead of logarithms.

Comment: Okay, thank you. I questioned doing that but wasn't convinced.

Answer (score 0):

Notice, the constant of integration may have positive or negative value.

using variable separable method as follows  $$\frac{dx}{dt}=rx^n$$
$$\frac{dx}{x^{n}}=rdt$$
$$\int x^{-n}\ dx=r\int dt$$
$$\frac{x^{-n+1}}{-n+1}=rt+c$$
$$x^{1-n}=(1-n)(rt+c)$$
Now, substituting another constant $\color{red}{c=-c_1}$ (as it makes no difference)
$$x^{1-n}=(1-n)(rt-c_1)$$
$$x=\left((1-n)(rt-c_1)\right)^{1/(1-n)}$$
$$x(t)=\left((n-1)(c_1-rt)\right)^{1/(1-n)}$$